# To show: $\omega(n)\ne\pi(n) , \forall n>2$

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that for $n>2$ ,  $\omega(n)<\pi(n)$ ? ( where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$ and $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes not exceeding $n$)

One thing is evident that $\omega(n)\le\pi(n) , \forall n>1$ , so what is required to prove is that $\omega(n)\ne\pi(n) , \forall n>2$

Answer (score 7):

Since $(n,n-1)=1$, so ,  $n$  it is not divisible  by prime divisors of $n-1$.

If $p\mid (n-1)$, of course, $p\lt n$

Comment: I had this feeling that using Bertrand's postulate was overkill... and there you go. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose not. Then $p \mid n$ for all primes $p \leq n$. Thus $2 \mid n$ so $n \geq 4$. By Bertrand's postulate, since $\frac{n}{2} \geq 2$, there is a prime $q$ strictly between $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$. Then clearly $q \nmid n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

In fact,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\omega(n)}{\pi(n)}=0  \tag{*}$$

It is obvious that $2^{\omega(n)}\leq n$, or

$$\omega(n)\leq \frac{\log n}{\log2} $$

according to prime number theorem,  (*) is right

[What is $\varlimsup \frac{\omega(n)}{\log n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808375/what-is-varlimsup-frac-omegan-log-n)